# High CPU utilisation with log4j2

Tags: performance, logging, log4j2, cpu-usage

I have an app for which my requirement is to maintain all User's log into single file and logging level is "info". I'm facing issue of high CPU utilization. Kindly find my log4j2.xml configuration and threaddump attached below.

```
    <Routing name="RoutingDeviceErrorLogFile">
        <Routes pattern="$">
            <Route>
                <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RoutingDeviceErrorLogFile"
                    fileName="${loghome}/RoutingDeviceErrorLogFile.log"
                    filePattern="${loghome}/%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-RoutingDeviceErrorLogFile-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
                    <!-- <PatternLayout> <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p- %m%n</Pattern> </PatternLayout> -->
                    <PatternLayout>
                        <Pattern>%d %p %-40C{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <Policies>
                        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                            modulate="true" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
                    </Policies>
                    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2000"/>
                </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>



    <Routing name="RoutingMainLogFile">
        <Routes pattern="$">
            <Route>
                <RollingRandomAccessFile name="MainLogFile"
                    fileName="${loghome}/MainLogFile.log" 
                    filePattern="${loghome}/%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-MainLogFile-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
                    <!-- <PatternLayout> <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p- %m%n</Pattern> </PatternLayout> -->
                    <PatternLayout>
                        <Pattern>%d %p %-40C{1.}[$${ctx:appIdUserId}]  %m%n</Pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <Policies>
                        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                    </Policies>
                    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5000"/>
                </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>


</Appenders>
<Loggers>

    <Logger additivity="false" level="OFF" name="org.springframework">
        <AppenderRef level="OFF" ref="RoutingMainLogFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger additivity="false" level="OFF" name="org.hibernate">
        <AppenderRef level="OFF" ref="RoutingMainLogFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger additivity="false" level="OFF" name="org.jboss">
        <AppenderRef level="OFF" ref="RoutingMainLogFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger additivity="false" level="OFF" name="org.apache">
        <AppenderRef level="OFF" ref="RoutingMainLogFile" />
    </Logger>
    
    <AsyncLogger name="com.xyz.abc.rest" level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="RoutingMainLogFile" level="DEBUG" />
    </AsyncLogger>

    <AsyncLogger name="com.xyz.abc.errorLogging" level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="RoutingDeviceErrorLogFile" level="ALL" />
    </AsyncLogger>
    
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="RoutingMainLogFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

This has become blocker for my app. I can't change the logging level to anything other than info.